# wordpress. выводятся только первые 5 записей из категории

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, cms, foreach

Я создал отдельный тип записи, поместил туда 10 записей. Но выводятся только первые 5 из них. Причем, проблема не в конкретных записях, так как я удалял их и создавал, что бы изменить порядок конкретных записей. Всегда выводятся только 5 самых старых записей. 
Вот код для этой записи из function.php

```
function getReviews(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'reviews'
    );

    $reviews = [];

    foreach (get_posts($args) as $post) {
        $review = get_fields($post->ID);
        $rwview['client_name_and_age'] = $post->post_title;
        $review['text'] = $post->post_content;
        $review['title'] = $post->post_title;
        $review['img'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'thumbnail');
        $reviews[] = $review;
    }

    return $reviews;
}
```

Вот как я вывожу записи в верстке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнительные поля создавал при помощи плагина Advanced Custom Fields

Если нужны  какие то дополнительные сведения - дайте знать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'reviews',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 - (ко-во постов на странице, -1 - все посты)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_posts()` имеет предустановленные параметры, в том числе `numberposts=5`.

Добавьте в args

```
numberposts=-1
```